# Frequent wifi disconnects on video calls with wireless router

Tags: networking, video, wireless-router

I have a basic belkin wireless router (model number - F7D1301 v1) for my home wifi. I experience frequent video and audio disconnects during video meetings over [zoom](https://zoom.us) (video conferencing) when connected to the wifi. If I connect directly to the broadband modem through the LAN cable I do not experience these problems. On troubleshooting I got to know that the LAN ports of my wireless router have stopped working.

Note that I can access internet and do any other work successfully over wifi just that the video calls over zoom are causing problems. I can verify my broadband speed through [speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/) which confirms that broadband speed isn't a problem. How do I troubleshoot the problem further. Please guide.

Thanks!

Comment: Use http://speedtest.dslreports.com/ to get your bufferbloat score with and without the router in the path.

Comment: I get a bufferbloat score of D with and without the router. I am not sure about the internet connection type so I did the test with both Cable & DSL type. The bufferbloat gauge is always red during the upload test. Here's a snapshot of the results - https://vgy.me/hZfEhP.png. I am not able to figure out what could be wrong. Does that give you any hint?

Comment: @Spiff - any comments?